# Does the RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False work for "1-x"

Tags: warning-messages, compile

I would like to pass a `CompiledFunction` to a `FindRoot` algorithm and therefore I use the option `RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False`. For example:

```
ff = Compile[x, x, RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False]
```

As expected and as demanded, the function does not evaluate when passing a non-numerical argument:

```
ff[a]

CompiledFunction[..][a]
```

However, when passing "1-a" the following warning appears:

```
ff[1 - a]

CompiledFunction::cfsa: Argument 1-a at position 1 should be a machine-size real number. >>
```

My question: Does MMA now use an uncompiled evaluation when returning:

```
ff[1-a]/.a->2
```

Unfortunately, I cannot relabel variables in my setup, due to the large number of occurrences of `1-a`

Comment: I'm inclined to say that the warning `CompiledFunction::cfsa` is unintended, *i.e.* it's a bug.  Since `ff[1-a]` still returns a `CompiledFunction` object, `f[1-a]/.a->2` should evaluate using compiled code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a warning message, which is issued because `1 - a` is not a variable (it is a normal expression with head `Plus`) and can be suppressed e.g. by setting `"WarningMessages" -> False`.

Uncompiled evaluation does not take place in

```
ff[1 - a] /. a -> 2
```

which can be checked by setting the `"RuntimeErrorHandler"` option.

Comment: +1, but it's not particularly obvious what counts as a "variable": `ff[Sin[x]]`, `ff[BesselJ[0, x]]`,  `ff[Sin[-x]]`, `ff[BesselJ[1/2, x]]` -- the latter two giving warnings, presumably because they have the head `Times` (after evaluating).  It seems to be whatever `expr` is accepted by `D` in `D[1, expr]`. (Silly example: `D[1, Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]`.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, `D` (and several other functions) use the same test to determine what *might* be a variable. It is a heuristic that explicitly forbids several common heads (including `List`, `Plus`, `Times`, `Equal`, `And`, `ConditionalExpression` etc.) but anything else is let through, and no, it hasn't been taught to care about `Sin`, `BesselJ` or `Plot`.

Comment: [Do you think this is a bug?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132458/12)