# Using a compiled function in NMinimize

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization, compile

I can get `NMinimize` to work with compiled functions in simple cases.

This works with a constraint:

```
poly1 = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, x^2 - y x + y^4, 
  RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}]

NMinimize[{poly1[x, y], Norm[{x, y}] < 1}, {x, y}]
NMinimize[{poly1 @@ {x, y}, Norm[{x, y}] < 1}, {x, y}]
```

Or, a domain specification:

```
NMinimize[{poly1 @@ {x, y}}, {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 1]]
```

This appears to work, but the `CompiledFunction` warnings makes me think that the compiled function is not being used:

```
poly2 = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, x[[1]]^2 - x[[2]] x[[1]] + x[[2]]^4, 
  RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}]
NMinimize[poly2[p], p ∈ Vectors[2, Reals]]
```

Another attempt didn't work at all:

```
poly3 = FunctionCompile[
  Function[{Typed[p, "NumericArray"::["Real64", 1]]}, 
   p[[1]]^2 - p[[1]] p[[2]] + p[[2]]^2]]

NMinimize[poly3[p], p ∈ Vectors[2, Reals]]
```

Can anyone see a way to get compiled functions to work with the domain specifications such as `Element[p,Disk[]]`?

Comment: `NMinimize[poly2[p], p \[Element] Disk[]]` seems to work, however it spits out several error messages. I would report this to Wolfram.

Comment: @DanielHuber Issue of `poly2` is a duplicate of this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127693/1871

Comment: @xzczd , So in light of Szbolcs's comment at the bottom of mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127693/1871 , should this considered a bug?  I'll report in any case.   However, I can't see why it is the same issue as in the linked post.

Comment: The warning is slightly different (`cfsa` v.s. `cfta`), but the behavior is the same: a warning pops up, but it's merely a warning, the `CompiledFunction[…][…]` is still unevaluated. (Just observe the output of `poly2[{a, b}]`, `"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False` does its work. ) I'm not sure if this should be considered a bug, but I agree this is worth reporting.

Comment: @xzczd I reported it. Thanks,